# Install barista/coffeescript on Rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am trying to get barista up and running in a Rails 2.3 application (that may not be moved to a new version of rails for the time beeing..). I switched the app to bundle so I added the following gems to my Gemspec:

```
gem "barista"
gem "json"
```

Then executed bundle install which run through. Now as far as I understand to "compile" the coffeescript there is a rake task that comes with barista. But it doesn't seem to be installed properly so I can use it with rake. I.e. when I execute rake -T there is no `barista:brew`

I saw a pending pull request on git hub suggesting to add require `'barista/tasks'` but that only resulted in rake not finding it. So what am I doing wrong or more general how do I get up and running with barista on Rails 2.3.x?

Comment: Under Rails 3, there is a `rails generate barista:install` generator. The primary effect of this generator is to (AFAICT) create an initializer called barista_config.rb and the rake task you mention. You can look at the template in the GitHub source and create your own.

Comment: @Steve Ross I did that actually and I guess I will do as you suggest and just create my own rake task or use Gurad i.e. guard-coffeescript to to all the compiling for me..

Comment: I'd use guard. If you don't mind doing the compile before deploy, guard is just fine. Also, look into `Jammit` (http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/), which doesn't address your same problem but will minify the output and package assets for easy deploy.

Comment: @Steve looks interesting I guess I'll have a look at that one.. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been some time ago since I used Barista and I have it not in use in any project, so I cannot verify it.

But I remember that one advantage of Barista is, that it waits serving a request until a modified CoffeeScript file is recompiled. This ensures that the browser doesn't request an outdated file.

So there is no need to compile the CoffeeScript files with a Rake task.

CoffeeScript itself comes also with a watch function, that compiles CoffeeScripts when a change is detected:

```
coffee -w /path/to/scripts
```

The reason why I stopped using Barista is simply that I discovered [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard). So I wrote [guard-coffeescript](https://github.com/guard/guard-coffeescript) to compile my CoffeeScripts in the same moment I save the file.

Guard-coffeescript has some advantages over Barista and CoffeeScript:

- Fast and low CPU consumption because it relies on file system modification events.
- Can be configured in many ways, e.g. multiple source folders and output folders.
- Immediate feedback when an error occurs, even with system notifications like Growl.

Comment: Danke für den Tipp! After playing still a bit more with barista I started using your guard extension for coffeescript it performs as advertised. :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that Rails 2 support for Barista is, according to Barista's README, "untested" (it was originally built for Rails 3 only), so there may be compatibility issues. Also note that you need either `therubyracer` gem, or the `node` binary on your system's PATH (or any of the other JS runtimes supported by [ExecJS](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs)).

Try this:

1. Add a file named `foo.coffee` to the folder `app/coffeescripts` with the contents

   `alert 'Hello, Barista!'`
2. Now add `<%= javascript_include_tag "foo" %>` to an ERB file and load that page.

You should get the alert, just as you would if the compiled `foo.js` were in `public/javascripts`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, sadly it does seem that barista isn't working right (at least on my machine..) for Rails 2. I guess I will just have to pre-compile all my coffee scripts.

Comment: @Mark Bummer. Well, you could also try the older [bistro_car](https://github.com/dcolthorp/bistro_car) (which requires you to have `coffee` on your PATH).

Comment: thanks for the tip, I might have a look at it but I'm actually quite pleased with the guard solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully integrated barista and rails 2.3.14.  In development, when I ask for a js file, the coffeescript file is found and compiled on the fly.

I also successfully ran the barista:brew rake task and the js files were generated.

I did notice that for production, unless I include an ExecJS compatible compiler, I need to precompile my js files before a push, which might be another +1 for the guard solution by @netzpirat.

For reference - I'm using Barista 1.3.0 and coffee-script 2.2.  Not sure how that affects things, but thought it was noteworthy.

Also, I added a line to load the barista tasks in my Rakefile:

```
# in my Rakefile
load "barista/tasks/barista.rake"
```

Comment: In the end, I had to remove barista and coffee->JS on fly compilation because it was red-lining my shared hosting and causing application failure.  It seems watching/compiling coffee->js was a little too much work for my server.  By simply running `coffee` with the watch option (as described above) all the coffee->js conversion happens during development time and checked into the codebase, leaving no need for Barista to run on the deployed server.